# Array causing program to crash c++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I am running into an issue in a program I am writing for class. When trying to change the value of an array element I get a window that says "Program has stopped working".

This code crashes my program:

```
case EAST:
    cout << "test";
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
        if (penDown)
            board[turtleY][turtleX + i] = 1; //this is the line causing the crash
        turtleX += spaces;
    }
break;
```

turtleX and turtleY are passed by reference into this function.

```
void moveForward(int spaces, bool penDown, int &turtleX, int &turtleY, int currentDirection, int board[][NUM_COLS]) {
switch (currentDirection) {
case NORTH:
    for (int i = 0; i > spaces; i--) {
        if (penDown)
            board[turtleY + i][turtleX] = 1;
            turtleY -= spaces;
    }
    break;
case EAST:
    cout << "test";
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
        if (penDown)
            board[turtleY][turtleX + i] = 1;
        turtleX += spaces;
    }
    break;
case SOUTH:
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
        if (penDown)
            board[turtleY + i][turtleX] = 1;
        turtleY += spaces;
    }
    break;

case WEST:

    break;
}
}
```

Comment: "The reason for the temp variables is because the program crashed when trying to use the referenced variables turtleX and turtleY
in the array parameters (Ex: board[turtleY+i][turtleX])" - well, maybe you should find out why that is, and fix it.

Comment: It's the same exact issue. I could remove the temp variables completely. In fact I'll edit the post now.

Comment: While you are at it, make sure to include a [mcve] so that we can actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is the value `tempX + 1` ever outside the range?

Comment: Should the statement `turtleY += spaces;` be `turtleY++`;?  Or maybe it should be moved *outside of the `for` loop*?  The code says you are adding `spaces * spaces` to the `turtleY` value; likewise for `turtleX`.  Use a debugger and single step through the loop.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you so much! Yes that was the problem. It was adding spaces to it every time, causing it to be out of range

Comment: Check out my answer.  Click on the check mark if the answer is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `spaces` to `turtleY` and `turtleX` in each of the loops.

I suggest you move the statement outside of the `for` loop:

```
case SOUTH:
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
        if (penDown)
            board[turtleY + i][turtleX] = 1;
    }
    turtleY += spaces;
    break;
```

Also, if you have not done so already, you need to do boundary checking before you adjust `turtleY` or `turtleX`, in all directions.